# How to access the IR sensor images in opencv

Tags: opencv, camera, infrared

I need to access the images from the IR sensor camera. Is it possible in opencv to access the images from IR sensor camera?

If it is possible can some one please guid e me with few links?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to 3d camera, thats what I understood from the term "IR Camera"

If I am right, then, the answer for you is "Yes !".
there are few libraries like, OpenNI, which are capable of extracting data and giving it to opencv for processing.

http://www.openni.org/

Download the SDK from the above link and also respective sensor driver incase you need, if you are using "Kinect for Windows", follow the below link, it turned out to be useful when i started things out.

http://yannickloriot.com/2011/03/kinect-how-to-install-and-use-openni-on-windows-part-1/#sthash.anacQErD.ly36SNRS.dpbs

if your able to run the openni samples through your camera, then the next step is using Cmake and building opencv with openNI, follow the below link to see how it can be done.

http://seevisionc.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/compiling-opencv-with-openni-for.html

after this, just try out the sample code "**openni_capture.cpp**" in your "**c:/opencv/samples/cpp**" directory which gives you an idea to proceed further

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The one I specified is infra red cmaera and not 3D camera.

Comment: This sounds a bit tricky,, 
 I am sure, openni is capable of handling the raw data of IR sensor camera and forward that to processing for an other library, but, I have no idea whether opencv is capable of dealing with this stuff or not.

but, conversion from ir sensor image to an rgb image is possible ( with false colors), that could be used in opencv for processing I guess.

Again, I am not sure about opencv, just guessing a probable suggestion as your question looks interesting.